lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle (version 2.18) jwt is taking too much time to generate token in prod env (2.40 seconds) symfony 6.4
New with lexik/ symfony / Docker and actually I'm running my first project on AWS (I know it's too much for a beginner).
It's a simple API that generates a token.
Stack
Symfony 6.4
Docker
Ubuntu LTS 22.04

In my local ENV, everything works fine (token generation is less than one second = 333ms).
When I run my project on Amazon, token generation takes more than 2 seconds, is that normal ?
I tried connecting to container on amazon and I executed a curl from inside the container, it also takes 2 seconds...
Authentication method is basic: I have one USER stored in database.
This is my security file:
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        #unip_ad_user_provider:
            #id: App\Security\ADUnip\ADUnipUserProvider
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/v1/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/v1/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        unsecure:
            pattern: ^/api/v1/doc
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~
        #main:
        #    lazy: true
        #    provider: users_in_memory

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/v1/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/v1/dev-route, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/v1/healthCheck, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

This is my nelmio config:
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        servers:
            #- url : '%env(HTTP_SERVER_URL)%'
            #  description: API over HTTP
            - url:  '%env(HTTPS_SERVER_URL)%'
              description: API over HTTPS
        info:
            title: API OCCEA/KSL EDITIQUE
            description: API REST pour les flux OCCEA Editique
            version: '%env(API_VERSION)%'
        components:
            securitySchemes:
                Bearer:
                    type: http
                    scheme: bearer
                    bearerFormat: JWT
        security:
            - Bearer: []
        paths:
            /api/v1/login:
                post:
                    tags:
                        - Web Services Editique
                    summary: GET JWT TOKEN
                    description: Web service for generating token.
                    operationId: getToken
                    security: []
                    requestBody:
                        required: true
                        content:
                            application/json:
                                schema:
                                    type: object
                                    properties:
                                        username:
                                            type: string
                                        password:
                                            type: string
                    responses:
                        '200':
                            description: Token response
                            content:
                                application/json:
                                    schema:
                                        type: object
                                        properties:
                                            token:
                                                type: string
                                                description: Token JWT
                        '400':
                            description: Bad request
                            content:
                                application/json:
                                    schema:
                                        type: object
                                        properties:
                                            code:
                                                type: integer
                                                description: status code of response
                                            message:
                                                type: string
                                                description: detail about error
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            #- ^/api/v1/(?!/doc|doc.json$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
            - ^/api/v1/contractDocuments # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
            # ONLY FOR TESTING = RE7
            - ^/api/v1/xmlForKsl # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
            # healthCheck
            - ^/api/v1/healthCheck # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc

Entrypoint.sh:
#!/bin/bash
# set -e
# Note: we don't just use "apache2ctl" here because it itself is just a shell-script wrapper around apache2 which provides extra functionality like "apache2ctl start" for launching apache2 in the background.
# (also, when run as "apache2ctl <apache args>", it does not use "exec", which leaves an undesirable resident shell process)

: "${APACHE_CONFDIR:=/etc/apache2}"
: "${APACHE_ENVVARS:=$APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars}"
if test -f "$APACHE_ENVVARS"; then
  . "$APACHE_ENVVARS"
fi
# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
: "${APACHE_RUN_DIR:=/var/run/apache2}"
: "${APACHE_PID_FILE:=$APACHE_RUN_DIR/apache2.pid}"
rm -f "$APACHE_PID_FILE"

# create missing directories
# (especially APACHE_RUN_DIR, APACHE_LOCK_DIR, and APACHE_LOG_DIR)

for e in "${!APACHE_@}"; do
  if [[ "$e" == *_DIR ]] && [[ "${!e}" == /* ]]; then
    # handle "/var/lock" being a symlink to "/run/lock", but "/run/lock" not existing beforehand, so "/var/lock/something" fails to mkdir
    #   mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lock': File exists
    dir="${!e}"
    while [ "$dir" != "$(dirname "$dir")" ]; do
      dir="$(dirname "$dir")"
      if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        break
      fi
      absDir="$(readlink -f "$dir" 2>/dev/null || :)"
      if [ -n "$absDir" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$absDir"
      fi
    done
    mkdir -p "${!e}"
  fi
done

echo "inside entrypoint.sh"

php --version

bin/console doctrine:database:create --no-interaction --if-not-exists --connection=default
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --allow-no-migration --no-interaction
php bin/console cache:clear

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/var
exec apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"

As I said before, everything works fine in my docker locally, issue start when it's on AWS (it generates the token but it takes too much time).

I edited my .env file to specify Postgres version.
I changed user provider (in_memory user), (I thought that this is database issue) => same thing.
Compared dockerfile (local - amazon container).
Checked envfiles

Expecting :
Fast token generation both in local and PRODUCTION (less than one second)
Problem :

token generation time is too long in production environment (/api/v1/login) // amazon (taking too much time.. more than 2 seconds).

PS:

local works fine (time generation = 330ms less than one second)

Feel free to make comments on my English :p

Are you sure this problem is related to Docker or Swagger? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

@NicoHaase, fist thing i checked env variables, then i trayed to make a curl inside container , then tryed to update version of Lexik. i thougt that this is an issue of performance but actually it is not because cpu is less than 20%.

@NicoHaase, the problem  is present only with /api/v1/login , the other routes are very fast in response. healtch check responds fast also.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

"i executed a curl from inside the container, it also takes 2 seconds." - what exactly does that mean? Which URL did you use for this? Any public available one, or one from your own application?

@NicoHaase the Project is on amazon AWS architecture, what i did is that i tried to make a curl  inside the api docker container in production to see total the time of execution => time execution to generate a token >= 2 seconds

You could try to enable Symfony's profiler to check where in the whole process so much time is consumed. Or, if this is your own Docker container, use a dedicated profiler like Blackfire or Tideways
